Dataview Query in Obsidian: Matching Role Entities with File Links in YAML Frontmatter
I am using Obsidian's Dataview plugin and have a YAML frontmatter structure in my note [[Person1]], which looks like this:
---
name: Person1
roles:
  - title: President
    entity: Entity1
    from: 2022-04-20
    to: 2024-02-19
  - title: CEO
    entity: Entity2
    from: 1996-05-15
    to: 2022-04-20
---

In my note [[Entity1]], I want to list all people with roles related to Entity1. I tried the following Dataview query:
TABLE WITHOUT ID file.link AS Persona, role.title AS Title, role.from AS From, role.to AS To, role.entity AS Entity
FROM ""
FLATTEN roles AS role
WHERE role.entity = this.file.name

This doesn’t work, but it does if I do
TABLE WITHOUT ID file.link AS Persona, role.title AS Title, role.from AS From, role.to AS To, role.entity AS Entity
FROM ""
FLATTEN roles AS role
WHERE contains(role.entity, this.file.name)

But it shows me also Entity2, and that's not what I want.
You could think that role.entity and this.file.name are different tyopes, but they're not, they're both string.
So it seems = operator does not work for roles.entity.
Any idea?
